# Select where has pattern in text column. sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi I'm sure this is possible but am not sure how to go about it.
In this case I want to find records that have text similar to this pattern '123-1234'

```
SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 'HAS pattern 3 numbers+ - + 4numbers'
```

I think the numbers are post codes perhaps.
Still bit of an sql noob.
Any helpers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the phone number is anywhere in the column:

```
SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```